How to safely change /etc/hosts file type from Unicode to ASCII on mac
I need to block some websites in hosts. But it didn't work, after modifying the file, I found it's in UTF-8 format instead of ASCII thanks to  OSX Sierra hosts file is ignored
How to safely change /etc/hosts file type from Unicode to ASCII? I'm a beginner mac user, so I don't want to make any harm

First of all, make a backup of your /etc/hosts file by running sudo cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.bak and then follow this guide to change the encoding of your /etc/hosts file https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/408181/changing-character-encoding-from-unicode-to-ascii

That question/answer you referenced is crap, unfortunately. Plain text files like /etc/hosts don't have any place to store metadata like what encoding is in use, so the file doesn't have any "encoding setting", so there's nothing to change. If your file contains any characters in (multi-byte) UTF-8 encoding and you want it to only contain 7-bit ASCII characters, simply delete the UTF-8 characters, leaving only 7-bit ASCII characters.

Or convert characters to ASCII with escape sequence: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742852/unicode-characters-in-urls

You really need to understand the problem better before trying to solve it. First, exactly what caused the change? I presume you used an editor on the file, but which one? Also, did any of the entries you added have funny characters in them (i.e. not plain English letters, periods, underscores, and dashes)? If so, they'll need to be converted to Punycode, not normal ASCII. It might also be you have something with a dash, but not a plain ASCII dash, in which case that's a different conversion.

I used a normal pico editor. I have added one long link of parallels website, it was really long, probably had some funny letters, but I'm not sure. The reason I have to mess with this file in the first place is because my Parallels app keeps showing an annoying pop up and I was told to clear the hosts or block it

You can't add links to /etc/hosts, only domain names (and the corresponding IP addresses). So it sounds like you're making invalid modifications to the /etc/hosts file, but I'd need more specifics of what you added to it to be sure.

Aah no links, got it. Then it's not about hosts file. Thank you.
